Latex2e ijmpa not producing pdf file in overleaf
I'm writing in overleaf using the style files provided here and when I compile the document I can see the pdf without any problems in the built-in viewer but it doesn't create a separate pdf file if one doesn't exist already. Is there a reason for this?

Did you file compile without errors? The fact that you casn see a PDF is not the same as the compilation went well. Sadly a lot of OverLeaf users ignore errors.

Yes the document compiles without errors. The template itself won't produce a pdf if you delete the pdf template and recompile

Can you share a link to the OverLeaf project or provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. Right now we do not know what you have done or added to the style.

Even using the template out of the box it produces this effect https://www.overleaf.com/4222212986bdjptxgkkssc#3b458c

It works just fine. Are you expecting to see the PDF in the list on the left? It is never present there (as the PDF lives somewhere else inside OverLeaf).  If you want to access the pdf just download it, using the menu button in the top left hand corner.

Oh ok, I expected to see the pdf file inside the project. My mistake, thanks for your help
